# why pyspark pandas udf grouped map serialization is designed this way?

Tags: pyspark, pyarrow

I am trying to get a concrete understanding on how the pandas UDF grouped map is working. While looking at the code here[1], i see that first the arrow object is converted into pandas series and then `pd.concat` is applied to create the full data frame.

What is confusing for me is , since arrow has support for Tabular format[2] and an API exist for converting table format to  pandas in pyarrow[3] , why is that not being used.

I am pretty sure i am missing out on something very basic, any pointers would be useful ?

[1] https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0494dc90af48ce7da0625485a4dc6917a244d580/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/serializers.py#L234-L276

[2] https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/tables.html

[3] https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.to_pandas